# MySQL - Working with Encrypted Columns

Tags: mysql, encryption, triggers, view

I have some tables with encrypted fields. After looking through the MySQL docs, I found that you can't create a custom datatype for encryption / decryption, which would be ideal. So, instead, I have a view similar to the one below:

```
CREATE VIEW EMPLOYEE AS
SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SUPER_SECURE_DECRYPT(SSN) AS SSN
FROM EMPLOYEE_ENCRYPTED
```

Again, after reading through the `MySQL` documentation, I've learned that the view isn't insertable because it has a derived column and the SSN field isn't updatable since it's a derived column, which makes sense. However, you can't add a trigger to a view so writing to the view is not really an option.

In an attempt to get around this, I've created a couple of triggers similiar to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_ENCRYPTED_UPDATE 
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE_ENCRYPTED FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.SSN <> OLD.SSN THEN 
        SET NEW.SSN = SUPER_SECURE_ENCRYPT(NEW.SSN);
    END IF;
END;
```

as well as one for inserting (which, since it's so similar, I'm not going to post it). This simply means I have to read from the view and write to the table.

This is a decent solution **except** that when you supply a `where` clause for the update statement that is querying the encrypted column (as in, update an employee by their SSN). Typically, this isn't an issue since I normally use the primary key for updates but I need to know for other encrypted fields if there's a way to do this.

I want to make `MySQL` do the heavy lifting for encryption and decryption so that it can be as frictionless as possible to work with as a developer. I would like the application developer to not have to worry about encrypted fields as much as possible while still using encrypted fields, that's the ultimate goal here. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is diffuclt to answer your question without knowing the type of encryption you are using.  It it's a standard encryption/hashing such as MD5, you can use that directly in MySQL with a `WHERE ssn=MD5('ssnStr')` type of clause, tho MD5 isn't meant for decryption.  Otherwise, if it's some sort of customized encryption, you'll have to either

1) create a procedure that performs the encryption/decryption and use that in your WHERE clause

or

2) perform the encryption before hand and use its result to match the condition you desire in your WHERE clause or wherever in your query.

It may be best to supply your query with the encrypted value for the SSN and use that to match  to your field.  If you have to perform some sort of decryption for each row in your DB, this won't be efficient at all.  In other words, supply your query with input that directly matches the data stored for best performance.